# how to redirect from stdin to dev driver

Tags: kernel, drivers, kernel-modules, devices

I am writing a device driver and have implemented `file_operations write` method.  I would also like to be able to just redirect to the device driver, e.g.:

```
echo "this text is sent to driver" > /dev/driver_name
```

I originally assumed this would magically work with the user space message being sent to the `.write` and the other parameters set accordingly.  LDD3 chapter 3 has some code which is pretty similar to mine, and the authors refer to testing/playing around both by invoking the write method directly and by redirecting to the driver (as I desire to do), making me think that I am on the right track.  However, when I tried redirecting to the driver, I received a "Permission denied" error and it did nothing.

Any direction/links/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you *have* permissions to write to the device file?

Comment: I sudo'd the above echo line.  the permissions are crw------- with root as owner.

Comment: You ran the echo with superuser privileges, not the shell.

Comment: ty.  How to make a driver install with different permissions?